# Newbye in pyomo : translate a Concrete problem into Abstract

Tags: pyomo

I'm encoutering some issues trying to translate a Contrete Model into Abstract one.

```
Months = RangeSet(6)
RequiredHours = {1: 8000, 2: 9000, 3: 9800, 4: 9900, 5: 10050, 6: 10500}
Notifications = {1: 2, 2: 0, 3: 2, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 0}
Costs = {'Attendants': 5100, 'Trainees': 3600}
Hours = {'Attendants': 150, 'Trainees': 25}
TraineeMax = 5

model = ConcreteModel()

model.TraineesNb = Var(Months,domain=NonNegativeIntegers,bounds=(0,TraineeMax))

AvailableAttendants = {}
AvailableTrainees = {}
for m in Months:
    if m == 1: 
        AvailableAttendants[m] = 62
        AvailableTrainees[m] = model.TraineesNb[m]
    if m == 2:
        AvailableAttendants[m] = AvailableAttendants[m-1] - Notifications[m-1]
        AvailableTrainees[m] = model.TraineesNb[m] + model.TraineesNb[m-1]
    if m > 2:
        AvailableAttendants[m] = AvailableAttendants[m-1] - Notifications[m-1] + model.TraineesNb[m-2]
        AvailableTrainees[m] = model.TraineesNb[m] + model.TraineesNb[m-1]
# Objective
model.Costs = Objective(
    expr = sum(AvailableAttendants[m] for m in Months)*Costs["Attendants"] + 
           sum(AvailableTrainees[m] for m in Months)*Costs["Trainees"] ,
           sense = minimize)
# declare constraints
model.NeededHours = ConstraintList()
for m in Months:
    model.NeededHours.add(expr = AvailableAttendants[m]*Hours["Attendants"] + 
                          AvailableTrainees[m]*Hours["Trainees"] >= RequiredHours[m])
```

The concrete model is forwarding the adequate resulys (perhaps not the most elegant code, but it works). In Discrete version of this model, an error occurs at the loop [for m in model.Months]
Thanks for your help and comments
Naji